# Clear visor or plain visor protect my eyes from bad rays

Tags: motorcycle, crash-helmet

You can see that this helmet has a clear(or transparent) visor. Due to the regulations here in my country, we cannot wear a tinted visor. So my question is this, will this avoid the harmful sun rays come to my eyes? I know I can wear a sunglass. But I don't like to do that. So what is your advice for me?

**Note:** I wear eyeglasses due to I have a vision problem on long distance. So will it too give extra safe to my eye with a transparent visor?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a helmet with a tinted visor inside the exterior clear visor. Would that be illegal in your area? They're more like sunglasses, functionally.

The tinted visor is easily deployed or stowed with one thumb on the go. The clear visor stays put.

There are a fair number of helmets with this feature in different feature/price ranges. Sorry, couldn't find a good picture.

I wear eye glasses and this is by far the best solution for me, and FAR more convenient than a tinted exterior shield.

Comment: What did you mean this? `I wear eye glasses`. Is that normal glass where you wear for some sort of eye problem or is that sunglass?

Comment: Me too wear eyeglasses due to I have a vision problem on long distance. So that will protect my eyes from bad rays? In other words, if I have both transparent helmet visor and eyeglass will save my eyes from bad rays?

Comment: I wear corrective lenses all the time (eye glasses). When I go out in the sun I wear corrective sunglasses. When I ride my motorcycle I can wear my normal, clear glasses and use the tinted visor built into the helmet. This tinted visor is different than the normal clear visor  you normally see on a full-face helmet.

Answer (score 4):

You should evaluate face shields for their rating in blocking UVA and UVB (the two bands of ultraviolet light that are of greatest concern in terms of skin and eye damage). Neither of these will require the shield to be tinted.

Note, this does not mean that the shield will also be polarized. You will still have to deal with annoying glare from reflections. However, you will have significantly less risk of cataracts in the long term.

Comment: How do I know my visor is compatible with this `UVA and UVB`? I can't see any label or like that on my visor about that,

Comment: Try searching the vendor website. I see ultraviolet blocking cited right up front for many products.